# What catalyst would make redtail catfish rise from the rivers and lakes and gain sentience?

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, post-apocalypse

so, writing up a post-apocalyptic fantasy world where humanity has left Earth and all it's cities and factories and farms behind, and, due to unknown catalyst, a race of amphibious humanoid catfish rose out of the water and established a rural society in the south coast of the USA over 10,000 years. These Catfish people are descended from an introduced population of Redtail Catfish.

But the question is: what event could speed up evolution to give Catfish sentience and a humanoid form within 10,000 years?

**Species Breakdown:**

- about the average height and build of your standard human
- inhabit a swampy environment
- semi-aquatic, have both gills and lungs
- bipedal, 4 limbs, two for walking on land, two for grasping, and a fishtail for swimming
- basically a human but is also a fish

Any sort of explanation is aye-ok with me

Comment: We require questions with a certain amount of specificity. If your looking for any complicated series of events over 10,000 years that results in sentient land dwelling catfish then you're more asking us to brainstorm, write a 10,000 year story, and build your world for you rather than some specific question suitable for this site.

Comment: @sphennings got it, won't do it again

Comment: Can you [edit] this post to ask a specific question more suitable to this site. That's our community's preferred resolution.

Comment: @sphennings sorry! it's done, I hope it's better

Comment: 10,000 years is bitten-by-a-radioactive-spider (Spiderman) grade evolution. If we look at what we understand about the [timeline of human evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_human_evolution), we learn that "we" were fish 505 million years ago and became "sentient" about 2.5 million years ago (folks will argue with me about that, but roll with it and don't miss my point). That's 502.5 million years of evolution that your catfish did in 10,000 years. Like I said, radioactive spider bite.

Comment: But I'm curious, we get questions like this periodically. They're next to impossible to answer because we barely understand evolution. It looks like we do because we have a mountain of information. But in reality, that mountain is just one grain in the mountain of information we need to understand to arbitrarily answer questions like this. What is it about your story or world write up that requires actually understanding the evolutionary pressures needed for one branch of the evolutionary tree to develop sentience? Remember, we can only explain tiny bits of how humans did it in hind sight.

Answer (score 4):

## Then the Aliens Came

[image]

10,000 years is too short for stupid catfish to become as smart as people, become humanoid, or even develop hands. It must be done artificially. For example by aliens.

For parsimony I suggest the aliens that caused the apocalypse are the same ones that created your uplifted catfish. You see these aliens have [as many arms as Vishnu and they are all very busy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zic0jWOV89M) using   [advanced cloning techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik0BPKM9WQg) to modify the catfish to become sentient.

If you prefer, the catfish were created not by the apocalypse aliens, but by a rival tribe of aliens who value sentient life and want to un-apocalypse the worlds the baddie aliens have destroyed.

They  goodie aliens   uplifted the catfish in particular, because the post-apocalypse Earth is hot and humid. Ideal for amphibian life to crawl onto land. And because these aliens have the same  chin barbels as the fish. The obvious choice to inherit the planet.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**No Natural Process will do this**

There is nothing that will make catfish sentient land dwellers in 10,000 years, short of major, sustained human genetic modification towards this goal, from a better understanding of biology than we have. We probably need 50 years to get to this level of understanding.

Here are the issues as I understand them:

1. Fish live in an aquatic environment, which supports their body. Their bones are cartilage, circulatory system and muscles are smaller and weaker than is needed to move on land. Basically, all that has to go. We're looking for a high powered land dwelling musculoskeletal system. This is the big advantage that made whales, dolphins and seals competitive when they returned to the sea. This is a big, brutal fix, and would take a huge number of gene replacements.
2. fish aren't the sharpest tool in the shed, for the most part. Surprisingly, I think this is easier to fix than the previous problem. We have some genes isolated for intelligence, in 50 years I suspect we'll have a decent map of them. Chuck those into some fish, with the right control sequences, and the fish should grow big brains, which, if the other tweeks haven't worked, will rapidly kill them, due to their relatively sluggish metabolism not being able to support the energy demands.
3. You'd be attempting to do this all with genes that work in humans, because we're the only sentient creature we know, so the obvious starting point. We're a massive evolutionary distance from fish, and there's going to be a whole bunch of genes that need something else, that work differently, that do something wholely unexpected. With the current state of biology, I'd assume 2-5 years worth of research for each gene. You're going to be replacing at a bare minimum, a couple of thousand.

It might be easier to give humans a head that looks like a catfish. I don't know how you'd do that either, but it's got to be simpler than trying to circumvent millions of years of evolution.

Note: unless the apocalypse happened thousands of years in the future, this is not *"lone mad researcher makes sentient fish"* territory. This is a larger undertaking than the moon landings, involving a similar number of people, with technology we don't have yet.

Comment: who said it had to be a natural process?

Comment: You specified evolution, which is a natural process. Even with literally anything we could do to speed evolution, there's no way you could get there in 10,000 years. It would have to be a program of sustained genetic modification

Comment: @redfrogcrab But I guess the big thing I wanted to point out is the sheer difficulty of getting catfish there. Getting, say, a sentient Labrador with hands? Comparatively simple. Sentient goat? Also comparatively easy. It's the sheer evolutionary distance from something with a big brain that walks on land that makes this hard

Comment: I'm a biologist IRL, and there's a world in which I can see it being possible to make monkeys or other mammals sentient, once we define sentience to a decent degree. I can also see cuttlefish or octopuses ending up at human level intelligence. But I don't know how we'd get there with catfish

Comment: @lupe Maybe we should  make the Labrador sentient first. Then get to work attaching fins and barbels to it.

Comment: @Daron I think it is genuinely easier to go this route, though still well outside what genetics can do, and even futher from what we're allowed to do. As the old genetics joke goes:
"What do you get if you cross an octopus with a turkey?"
"A severe rebuke from the ethics committee, and immediate suspension of research funding"

Comment: @lupe Sounds good! How about you get started with the gene-sequencing and neurochemistry and I will start on the barbels? I got some new hot glue gun rods from the hardware store last week and I am looking for an excuse to try them out.

Comment: Deal, think we can have this whole thing wrapped up in a couple of weeks. Not sure where we get the Labrador from, but the neighbors have one who always pees on our fence, so I guess that'd do